# How to render a single data from an api call in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have done the api call this way, I am able to see the return array in network, it has a single array with store details, I have to output the store name, how to render it, I am familiar with map function to display lista. How to render a single output

```
import StoreService from "../../services/Store/store.service";
import { Store } from "../../models/Store/store.model";
    
    interface OfferListProps {
        activeStoreId: string;
    }
    
    function Overview(props: OfferListProps) {
        const { activeStoreId } = props;
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
        const [stores, setStores] = useState<Store[]>([]);
    
        const handleFetchStore = () => {
            StoreService.fetchStores(
                (store: Store[]) => {
                    setStores(stores);
                },
                () => { },
                () => { }
            );
        };
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (activeStoreId) {
                handleFetchStore();
            }
        }, [activeStoreId]);
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to fetch all stores `StoreService.fetchStores` for a single store display?

Comment: can you tell me the real way to do it ?

Comment: you can check `StoreService` to find something like `fetchStore` (not `fetchStores`) that would help you get a single store by store id. If it's not there, I can help you out with a workaround

Comment: I have `showStore` in `StoreService`

Comment: `static showStore(
        storeId: string,
        onSuccess: Function,
        onError: Function,
        onFinal: () => void
    ) {
        const API_URL = ApiRoutes.STORES_URL + '/' + storeId;
        return axiosInstance
            .get(API_URL)
            .then(response => {
                const store = deserialize(Store, response.data["store"]);
                onSuccess(store);
            })
            .catch(error => {

                onError(error);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                onFinal();
            })
    }`

Comment: Perfect! let me reuse it and put some code under answer section, this section is not enough space to explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an array in the state, you can pass an object for a single store rendering

```
const [store, setStore] = useState<Store>();
```

```
import StoreService from "../../services/Store/store.service";
import { Store } from "../../models/Store/store.model";
    
    interface OfferListProps {
        activeStoreId: string;
    }
    
    function Overview(props: OfferListProps) {
        const { activeStoreId } = props;
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
        const [store, setStore] = useState<Store>(); //only set a single store
    
        const handleFetchStore = (storeId) => {
            StoreService.showStore(storeId,
                (store: Store) => {
                    setStore(store); //set store data
                },
                () => { },
                () => { }
            );
        };
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (activeStoreId) {
                handleFetchStore(activeStoreId);
            }
        }, [activeStoreId]);
```

After this, you can use `store` for rendering